# Как с помощью стилей нарисовать сетку с пагинацией, как на рисунке?

Tags: html, css, pagination

Есть блок с пагинацией. Интересует, как с помощью `css` сделать аналогичную сеточную нумерацию - хотелось бы не вводить лишние теги и сделать систему легко расширяемой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую этого добиться с помощью псевдоклассов, но пока застопорился - [Фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/2799/)

```css
#pagination {
  text-align: center;
}

#pagination .pagination {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#pagination .pagination>li {
  position: relative;
}

#pagination .pagination>li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  border-left: 1px solid #c4c2c2;
  border-right: 1px solid #c4c2c2;
  width: 31.56px;
  height: 11px;
}

#pagination .pagination>li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -39px;
  border-left: 1px solid #c4c2c2;
  border-right: 1px solid #c4c2c2;
  width: 31.56px;
  height: 11px;
}

#pagination .pagination>li>a {
  color: #c4c2c2;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  border: 1px solid #c4c2c2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav id="pagination" aria-label="...">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item active">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">3 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```css
#pagination {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pagination:before,
.pagination:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  left: -60px;
  right: -60px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eae5e5;
}

.pagination:before {
  top: -1px;
}

.pagination:after {
  bottom: -1px;
}

.pagination-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.pagination-item:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  top: -30px;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: -30px;
  border-left: #eae5e5 solid 3px;
  border-right: #eae5e5 solid 3px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.pagination-item:before {
  left: 0px;
  top: -30px;
  bottom: -30px;
}

.pagination-item:last-child:after {
  right: 0px;
  top: -30px;
  bottom: -30px;
}

.pagination-item:first-child:after,
.pagination-item:last-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eae5e5;
}

.pagination-item:first-child:after {
  left: -30px;
  right: 100%;
}

.pagination-item:last-child:after {
  right: -30px;
  left: 100%;
}

.pagination-link {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #c6c3c3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.pagination-link:before,
.pagination-link:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background: #eae5e5;
  height: 3px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.pagination-link:before {
  left: 0px;
}

.pagination-link:after {
  right: 0px;
}

.pagination-item.active .pagination-link {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.pagination-item.active .pagination-link:before,
.pagination-item.active .pagination-link:after,
.pagination-link:hover:before,
.pagination-link:hover:after {
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagination">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="pagination-item"><a class="pagination-link">1</a></li>
    <li class="pagination-item"><a class="pagination-link">2</a></li>
    <li class="pagination-item active"><a class="pagination-link">3</a></li>
    <li class="pagination-item"><a class="pagination-link">4</a></li>
    <li class="pagination-item"><a class="pagination-link">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Например:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination__list {
  display: flex; 
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.pagination__link {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #777;
  border:1px solid #777;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
}


.active .pagination__link,
.pagination__link:hover {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pagination__link:after {
  content:'';
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #777;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.active .pagination__link:after,
.pagination__link:hover:after{
  width: 0px;
}

.pagination__item {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border:1px solid #777;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
}

.pagination__item:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
}

.pagination__item:first-child:after,
.pagination__item:first-child:before,
.pagination__item:last-child:after,
.pagination__item:last-child:before {
  content:'';
  width: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #777;
  position: absolute;
}

.pagination__item:first-child:before {  
  top:10px;
  left: -10px;
}

.pagination__item:first-child:after {  
  bottom:10px;
  left: -10px;
}

.pagination__item:last-child:before {  
  top:10px;
  left: 100%;
}

.pagination__item:last-child:after {  
  bottom:10px;
  left: 100%;
}

.pagination__item:first-child .pagination__link:before,
.pagination__item:last-child .pagination__link:before{
  content:'';
  width: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #777;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.pagination__item:first-child .pagination__link:before {  
  left:-10px;
}
.pagination__item:last-child .pagination__link:before {
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <ul class="pagination__list">
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <a href="#" class="pagination__link">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <a href="#" class="pagination__link">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pagination__item active">
      <a href="#" class="pagination__link">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <a href="#" class="pagination__link">4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <a href="#" class="pagination__link">5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```